# How do I create a package.json file?

Tags: json, node.js, npm, npm-install

In Mac [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(macOS)#Terminal):

```
package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/stickupartist/portfolio/npm-debug.log
stickup-artists-macbook-pro:portfolio stickupartist$ npm init
This utility will walk you through creating a package.json file.
```

What utility is being referred to?

And next:

```
Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package
and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Name: (portfolio)
```

I type:

```
npm install <portfolio> --save
```

And the terminal prints out:

```
Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.
```

What am I doing wrong with my naming? I'm working on my local machine with [Meteor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28web_framework%29), on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 11):

To create the `package.json` file, you can run [npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) (and go through its options) or manually create the file based on [these rules](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

Here's a simple `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my-cool-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is my cool app",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.1.1",
  }
}
```

Now, as far as the error:

> Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters.

It means that the package name doesn't meet one of the [naming rules](https://github.com/npm/validate-npm-package-name#naming-rules), mainly:

> package name must not contain any non-url-safe characters (since name ends up being part of a URL)

This is most likely happening because you wrapped your package name in `<>`.

`<>` means it is a placeholder for a value. When actually typing it in, you should overwrite it (and anything it wraps) with some appropriate value, in this case a valid package name.

It is how you would define an `npm install` command, not use it:

Definition:

```
npm install <package_name_goes_here>
```

Usage

```
npm install portfolio
```

Comment: Thanks for responding nem: I tried 'npm init' and got 'name: (portfolio) npm WARN init canceled'. Then 'Use `npm install <pkg> --save` afterwards to install a package and
save it as a dependency in the package.json file.

Press ^C at any time to quit.
name: (portfolio)

Comment: I'm willing to try to do it manually. Where do I save package.json to? Thank you!

Comment: It would be best for you to read more about [npm init](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) itself. Their documentation will explain everything. And you need to create `package.json` in the root (top) directory of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks for the definition! I ran it and it installed the package.json in the root directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use: `npm init -y`

Then install your packages.

That worked for me when I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

See [nem035's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691669/how-do-i-create-a-package-json-file/39691697#39691697) to create package.json (just `npm init`).

For your other problem: in `npm install <pkg> --save`  refers to the name of a package. You can install the package with its name, without brackets. For example, `npm install portfolio --save`

Answer (score -2):

Log out of the session. Then re-login and try **npm install -y**. This has worked for me.