# How to create package.json for install node dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to install dependencies by `npm install`, there is need a `package.json` file that should include all the dependencies that need to install. I am not aware of how to create that `package.json` file.

These are the dependencies that I want to install by run only `npm install`:
1- MySQL,
2- express,
3- request,
4- md5,
5- nodemailer,
6- google-polyline.

Comment: Run `npm init -y` to create an empty package.json, then `npm i <dependency-1> <dependency-2> ...`. Otherwise you need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691669/how-do-i-create-a-package-json-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

package.json file is modified automatically when you add some dependencies.

In the very beginning you need to initialize your app with:

`npm init`

then install what you need use:
`npm i mysql`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

and so on for other dependencies

Answer (score 2):

You can run `npm init` to run a questionnaire to generate a `package.json` or run `npm init -y` to generate a default `package.json`.

See this [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file#creating-a-new-packagejson-file).

Here is how a default `package.json` looks like:

```
{
    "name": "my_package",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
      "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package.git"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "bugs": {
      "url": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ashleygwilliams/my_package"
  }
```

Then when you run `npm install some_package` it will be added to the `denpendencies`.